# How to use LINQ to select all descendants of a composite object

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, linq-to-objects, composite

How can I make `ComponentTraversal.GetDescendants()` better using LINQ?

## Question

```
public static class ComponentTraversal
{
    public static IEnumerable<Component> GetDescendants(this Composite composite)
    {
        //How can I do this better using LINQ?
        IList<Component> descendants = new Component[]{};
        foreach(var child in composite.Children)
        {
            descendants.Add(child);
            if(child is Composite)
            {
                descendants.AddRange((child as Composite).GetDescendants());
            }
        }
        return descendants;
    }
}
public class Component
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Composite: Component
{
    public IEnumerable<Component> Children { get; set; }
}
public class Leaf: Component
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

## Answer

I edited Chris's answer to provide a generic extension method that I've added to my Common library.  I can see this being helpful for other people as well so here it is:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetDescendants<T>(this T component, Func<T,bool> isComposite, Func<T,IEnumerable<T>> getCompositeChildren)
    {
        var children = getCompositeChildren(component);
        return children
            .Where(isComposite)
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetDescendants(isComposite, getCompositeChildren))
            .Concat(children);
    }
```

Thanks Chris!

### Also,

Please look at LukeH's answer at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/03/23/all-about-iterators.aspx .  His answer provides a better way to approach this problem in general, but I did not select it because it was not a direct answer to my question.

Comment: If it works now, why would you change it? Merely because Linq looks fancier? Or do you expect to have a performance gain? Personally I wouldn't change a working method just for these reasons, "better" is therefore very subjective.

Comment: @Bazzz, In every child composite I instantiate a new array.  I'm hoping there is a more cost-efficient way and it makes sense that LINQ could be it.  I also might want to do this sort of thing against an IQueryable, in which case LINQ would definitely create a performance benefit.  However the biggest reason I have for wanting to know how to do it in LINQ is that I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = composite.Children.OfType<Composite>().SelectMany(child => child.GetDescendants()).Concat(composite.Children);
return result.ToList();
```

When doing a translation from imperitive syntax to LINQ, it is usually pretty easy to take the translation one step at a time.  Here is how this works:

1. This is looping over composite.Children, so that will be the collection we apply LINQ to.
2. There are two general operations occuring in the loop, so lets do one of them at a time
3. The "if" statement is performing a filter.  Normally, we would use "Where" to perform a filter, but in this case the filter is based on type.  LINQ has "OfType" built in for this.
4. For each child composite, we want to recursively call GetDescendants and add the results to a single list.  Whenever we want to transform an element into something else, we use either Select or SelectMany.  Since we want to transform each element into a list and merge them all together, we use SelectMany.
5. Finally, to add in the composite.Children themselves, we concatenate those results to the end.

Comment: Beware that nested iterators can can potentially huge performance costs. See the "Cost of Iterators" section of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/03/23/all-about-iterators.aspx for more info.

Comment: @LukeH, this code at least does not suffer from the linked issues because it does nest particularly deeply and flattens the results to a List at each step.

Comment: I put a generic version of the extension method in the question.  I just altered your code a little bit.  It might be helpful for future users if you included it at the end your answer (since they don't expect to see it in the question).  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5):

There are often good reasons to avoid *(1)* recursive method calls, *(2)* nested iterators, and *(3)* lots of throwaway allocations. This method avoids all of those potential pitfalls:

```
public static IEnumerable<Component> GetDescendants(this Composite composite)
{
    var stack = new Stack<Component>();
    do
    {
        if (composite != null)
        {
            // this will currently yield the children in reverse order
            // use "composite.Children.Reverse()" to maintain original order
            foreach (var child in composite.Children)
            {
                stack.Push(child);
            }
        }

        if (stack.Count == 0)
            break;

        Component component = stack.Pop();
        yield return component;

        composite = component as Composite;
    } while (true);
}
```

And here's the generic equivalent:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetDescendants<T>(this T component,
    Func<T, bool> hasChildren, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildren)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    do
    {
        if (hasChildren(component))
        {
            // this will currently yield the children in reverse order
            // use "composite.Children.Reverse()" to maintain original order
            // or let the "getChildren" delegate handle the ordering
            foreach (var child in getChildren(component))
            {
                stack.Push(child);
            }
        }

        if (stack.Count == 0)
            break;

        component = stack.Pop();
        yield return component;
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: +1, Thanks for your answer. I updated the question to include a note about this.  You have probably provided the best approach to the solution, but I didn't select you because it was not an answer to the actual question I posted.

Comment: @smartcaveman: Fair enough, although it's often necessary to write an extension method and add it to your library of tools rather than trying to bend the built-in LINQ methods to your requirements. For example, with the generic version of my answer you can do something like `var descendents = rootComponent.GetDescendents(x => x is Composite, x => ((Composite)x).Children);`.

Comment: I would use your extension method with IEnumerable<T> implementations, but it has a disadvantage in that it is not compatible with an IQueryable<T>, (which is the reason that bending built-in LINQ methods sometimes makes sense - to be compatible with existing LINQ providers).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about better, but I think this performs the same logic:

```
public static IEnumerable<Component> GetDescendants(this Composite composite)
{
    return composite.Children
                .Concat(composite.Children
                            .Where(x => x is Composite)
                            .SelectMany(x => x.GetDescendants())
                );
}
```

It might be shorter, but there is nothing wrong with what you have.  As I said above, this is supposed to perform **the same** thing and I doubt that the performance of the function is improved.

Comment: There is a slight important difference: This method uses deferred execution and only pays execution cost as it iterates the structure.  If the entire structure does not need to be explored (we can short circuit when we find a result, for example), then this has advantages.

Comment: Beware though that nested iterators can can potentially huge performance costs. See the "Cost of Iterators" section of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/03/23/all-about-iterators.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example for when you might want to implement an iterator. This has the advantage of lazy evaluation in a slightly more readable syntax. Also, if you need to add additional custom logic then this form is more extensible

```
 public static IEnumerable<Component> GetDescendants(this Composite composite)
    {
        foreach(var child in composite.Children)
        {
            yield return child;
            if(!(child is Composite))
               continue;

            foreach (var subChild in ((Composite)child).GetDescendants())
               yield return subChild;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Beware that nested iterators can can potentially huge performance costs. See the "Cost of Iterators" section of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/03/23/all-about-iterators.aspx for more info.