# Select parent and children when type is the same with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object like this

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Employee> Employees{ get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is select all of the employees, plus the parent employee in a single collection.  I want to have the parent as the first item in the collection for paging.  Right now I am doing something like this

```
Employee emp = getEmployeeFromService();
var allEmps = new List<Employee>();
allEmps.Add(emp);
allEmps.AddRange(emp.Employees);

var pagedEmployees= (from e in allEmps select e).Skip(offset).Take(pageSize);
```

Is there a better way to do this with a single linq statement?

Comment: Never write `(from e in whatever select e)`.  It's useless.

Comment: Right, you can just do `allEmps.Skip(offset).Take(pageSize);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
var pagedEmployees = new [] { emp }.Concat(allEmps).Skip(offset).Take(pageSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question: [How to use LINQ to select all descendants of a composite object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262201/how-to-use-linq-to-select-all-descendants-of-a-composite-object/5263080#5263080) .

Answer (score 0):

For a list of employees:

```
 employees.Concat(employees.SelectMany(x => x.Employees)).Skip(offset).Take(pageSize);
```

Example (outputs 7):

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {

    }

    public Employee(int count)
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
        List<Employee> list = Employees as List<Employee>;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Employee());               
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> employees = new Employee[]
                                            {
                                                new Employee(3),
                                                                new Employee(2)
    };


        IEnumerable<Employee> enumerable = employees.Concat(employees.SelectMany(x => x.Employees));


        Console.WriteLine(enumerable.Count());
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```