# Composite iteration failure (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, design-patterns, composite

Below is a first attempt at using a Composite pattern.

It works in the sense that I can arbitrarily nest and get the correct results for the Duration property, with is the focus of the composition. BUT has a coding problem in that the iteration over the children needed to output the composite's ToString() fails:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

The are a few extension methods for GetDescendents in this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262201/how-to-use-linq-to-select-all-descendants-of-a-composite-object), including one that uses a stack to avoid the expense of recursion and 
nested iterators.

I would like to understand the pattern better first though, so I have a few questions here:

- How can I change the existing iteration code to prevent this error? I know how to convert it to a Linq equivalent but I want to leave it as the loops until I understand what is wrong with it.
- Is it typical in the Composite to provide a Count property, or somehow cache the count after an iteration?
- in the general case where you don't need a specialized collection, would you typically have your Children property be IEnumerable, IList, or List?

Any good links for examples of working (non-trival) .net code would also be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Berryl

## CODE

```
public interface IComponent    {
    void Adopt(IComponent node);
    void Orphan(IComponent node);

    TimeSpan Duration { get; }
    IEnumerable<IComponent> Children { get; }
}

public class Allocation : Entity, IAllocationNode    {

    public void Adopt(IAllocationNode node) { throw new InvalidOperationException(_getExceptionMessage("Adopt", this, node)); }
    public void Orphan(IAllocationNode node) { throw new InvalidOperationException(_getExceptionMessage("Orphan", this, node)); }

    public IEnumerable<IAllocationNode> Allocations { get { return Enumerable.Empty<IAllocationNode>(); } }

    public virtual TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
}


class MyCompositeClass : IAllocationNode {
         public MyCompositeClass() { _children = new List<IAllocationNode>(); }

        public void Adopt(IAllocationNode node) { _children.Add(node); }
        public void Orphan(IAllocationNode node) { _children.Remove(node); }

        public TimeSpan Duration {
            get {
                return _children.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (current, child) => current + child.Duration);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<IAllocationNode> Children {
            get {
                var result = _children;
                foreach (var child in _children) {
                    var childOnes = child.Children;
                    foreach (var node in childOnes) {
                        result.Add(node);
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
       private readonly IList<IAllocationNode> _children;

        #endregion

        public override string ToString() {
            var count = Children.Count();
            var hours = Duration.TotalHours.ToString("F2");
            return string.Format("{0} allocations for {1} hours", count, hours);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I change the existing
>   iteration code to prevent this error?

The exception is occurring because the code in the `Children` property's getter is modifying a collection *while* iterating over it.

You appear to be under the impression that the code

```
var result = _children;
```

creates a copy of the *list* referred to by the `_children` field. It does not, it just copies the *reference* to the list (which is what the value of the field represents) to the variable.

An easy fix to copy the list over is to instead do:

```
var result = _children.ToList();
```

> I know how to convert it to a Linq
>   equivalent.

The LINQ equivalent of your current code, which should work in a lazy manner, is:

```
return _children.Concat(_children.SelectMany(child => child.Children));
```

EDIT:
I was originally under the impression that your code was limiting the traversal-depth to two levels (children and grandchildren), but now I can see that this is not the case: there is indeed a recursive call to the *property* `Children` rather than just the value of the *field* `_children`. This naming is quite confusing because the property and the 'backing' field represent different things entirely. I strongly recommend that you rename the property to something more meaningful, such as `Descendants`.

Comment: @Ari. Yeah, that fixes it. I am not seeing where I am limiting the depth of the traversal though - how would you modify this to get ALL decendents?

Comment: spelled your name wrong there, sorry. I am not seeing where I am limiting the depth of the traversal- how would you modify this to get ALL decendents? Cheers