# Composite Design pattern & common descendant methods

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns, composite

I am using a composite pattern as shown in the class diagram below. Basically my primary leaf (an Allocation) has a single property, Duration, that I want to accumulate in various composites.

I also want to have a count of allocations, and the ability to return the allocations as a collection I can use for data binding in presentations.

This question is about the C# implementation, specifically:

1. There is an interesting [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262201/how-to-use-linq-to-select-all-descendants-of-a-composite-object) that has an extension to do this recursively, as well as an alternative approach that avoids recursion altogether. Would you have a common method to get at the Allocations the way I am doing? I haven't decided yet if the code I wrote feels awkward because I am not comfortable with pattern, or if it *is* awkward!
2. Do you see any easy opportunities here to cache the results of the first iteration and thereby minimize further iteration?

Cheers,
Berryl

[image: this class diagram]

## Code in the Composite class

```
public class AllocationComposite : AllocationNode
{
    protected readonly IList<AllocationNode> _children;
    public AllocationComposite() { _children = new List<AllocationNode>(); }

    #region Implementation of AllocationNode

    public override void Adopt(AllocationNode node) ...
    public override void Adopt(IEnumerable<AllocationNode> nodes)...
    public override void Orphan(AllocationNode node)...
    public override void Orphan(IEnumerable<AllocationNode> nodes)...

    public override IEnumerable<AllocationNode> Descendants
    {
        get
        {
            return _children.Concat(_children.SelectMany(child => child.Descendants));
        }
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Allocation> Allocations
    {
        get
        {
            return Descendants.OfType<Allocation>();
        }
    }

    public override TimeSpan Duration {
        get {
            return Allocations.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (current, child) => current + child.Duration);
         }
    }

    public override int Count { get { return Allocations.Count(); } }

    #endregion

    public override string ToString() {
        return String.Format("{0} for {1}", 
            "allocation".PluralizeWithCount(Count), 
            "hour".PluralizeWithCount(Duration.TotalHours, "F2"));
    }
}
```

}

## Default implementation in abstract Component

```
public abstract class AllocationNode: Entity, IAllocationNode
{
    #region Implementation of AllocationNode

    public virtual TimeSpan Duration { get { return TimeSpan.Zero; } set {  } }

    public virtual void Adopt(AllocationNode node) { throw new InvalidOperationException(...)); }
    public virtual void Adopt(IEnumerable<AllocationNode> nodes) { throw new InvalidOperationException(...)); }
    public virtual void Orphan(AllocationNode node) { throw new InvalidOperationException(...)); }
    public virtual void Orphan(IEnumerable<AllocationNode> nodes) { throw new InvalidOperationException(...)); }

    public virtual int Count { get { return 1; } }

    public virtual IEnumerable<AllocationNode> Descendants { get { return Enumerable.Empty<AllocationNode>(); } }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Allocation> Allocations { get { return Enumerable.Empty<Allocation>(); } }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do you want to have a collection of all nodes flattened (IEnumerable allNodes)? If so, after a quick look at the post you linked, I think that both solutions are OK. If the cosiderations LukeH mentions don't apply to your case, I would stick to LINQ solution because of its clarity, but it's up to you.
2. Caching is easy if you don't modify your structure. It gets very complicated if addition and deletions take place. 
   Anyway, what do you want to achieve with caching? Have the descendants count cached? Descendants themselves? On which level? Root level or any level?

If you have an abstract class, it would be more elegant to make its methods abstract rather than virtual throwing exceptions or returning empty collections.

PS. The class diagram is not synchronized with the code (i.e. placement of Duration property)

Comment: nice quick analysis! i had previously had an interface instead of an abstract class which made the degenerate common operations in the leaf Allocation. That didn't seem elegant at all so I thought I upgraded by having the abstract class, which I did as I was writing this post (not surprised my class diagram was a bit off). In fact, if I made those methods abstract I would wind up having to put them back in the leaf, no?

Comment: I also thought that having some of those ugly methods was part of the price of giving client transparency in dealing with the composite structure. They *are* ugly tho..

Comment: yes, when it comes to the Allocations enumeration I want flattenned nodes. If you have something more elegant in mind I would love to see it tho

Comment: yeah, there will be additions & deletions but would love to see a quick sample in code of how you would cache the count at any level. Cheers

Comment: Not sure now what you meant about the Duration placement property (the setter?). That is another awkward bit actually - the leaf *has* to be able to modify Duration while it is nonsensical for the composite to do so - hence an empty setter in the abstract class.